# How to install BaseBox to switch with PoE

Tags: router, power-over-ethernet

I have a MikroTik BaseBox 2 and a PoE without any Antenna. I want to connect that BaseBox to a switch which is connected an optical fiber in it (Internet).
**How can I connect a BaseBox to a switch with PoE and without Antenna?**
(at the end I want config a HotSpot with BaseBox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is somewhat unclear, but I think I understand what you're going for.

```
---------     --------
|Basebox|-----|Switch|-----Internet
---------     --------
```

The answer is that it's basically plug and play. If the switch supports passive PoE around 12-24 volts, then simply enable that and plug an Ethernet cable between the two. If it does not support passive, then you either have to use a separate PoE injector, use a different switch, or use an 802.3af to passive converter such as [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01BE5UL4Y).

Then you just need to configure the router to your specifications.

Comment: I solved my issue myself but your answer has good info too